# c - skyline algorithm confusion

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to write a code which gives coordinates of corners of a skyline, it was one of my friends' homework and I am trying it as a practice for myself. So, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct building 
{
    int start, height, width;
} BUILDING;


int main() 
{
    FILE *buildingsptr, *outlineptr;
    char karakter;
    int satir = 1, i = 0, j = 0, *heights, lastpoint = 0 ;
    BUILDING *ptr, *a, temp;

    buildingsptr = fopen("buildings.txt", "r");

    if (buildingsptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("An error occured while opening the file.\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
    while ((karakter = fgetc(buildingsptr)) != EOF)
    {
        if (karakter == '\n') satir++;
    }

    ptr = (BUILDING *) malloc(satir * sizeof(BUILDING));

    a = ptr;

    rewind(buildingsptr);

    for (i = 0; i < satir; i++)
    {
        fscanf(buildingsptr, "%d %d %d", &ptr->start, &ptr->height, &ptr->width);
        ptr++;
    }
    fclose(buildingsptr);
    ptr = a; // a is for accessing the first part of the allocated memory,
             // compiler gave some errors while I tried to access the first
             // block of the array.

    for (j = 0; j < satir; j++) //bubble sort to buildings
    {
        for (i = 0; i < satir; i++)
        {
            if (ptr[i].start > ptr[i + 1].start)
            {
                temp = ptr[i];
                ptr[i] = ptr[i + 1];
                ptr[i + 1] = temp;
            }//end of if
        }//end of second for
    }//end of first for

    lastpoint = ((ptr[satir - 1].start + ptr[satir - 1].width) + 1);
    heights = (int *)calloc(lastpoint, sizeof(int));


    for (j = 0; j < lastpoint; j++) // j travels the x axis
    {
        for (i = 0; i < satir; i++) // i counts buildings
        {
            if (j <= (ptr[i].start + ptr[i].width && ptr[i].start <= j))
            {
                if (ptr[i].height > heights[i])
                    heights[i] = ptr[i].height;
            }
        }
    }

    outlineptr = fopen("outline.txt", "w");

    for (i = 0; i < lastpoint; i++) // for every point x,checking the heights
                                    // and transforming them as the coordinates
    {
        if (heights[i + 1] > heights[i])
        {
            fprintf(outlineptr, "(%d,%d),", i + 1, heights[i]);
            fprintf(outlineptr, "(%d,%d),", i + 1, heights[i + 1]);
        }//end if
        if (heights[(i + 1)] < heights[i])
        {
            fprintf(outlineptr, "(%d,%d),", i, heights[i]);
            fprintf(outlineptr, "(%d,%d),", i, heights[i + 1]);
        }//end if
    }//end for
    fprintf(outlineptr, "(%d,%d),", lastpoint, heights[lastpoint]);
    fprintf(outlineptr, "(%d,%d)", lastpoint, 0);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Code is working but it is writing wrong coordinates to the outline.txt. "buildings.txt" is something like:

```
24 7 4
5 7 11
26 9 7
9 5 5
3 12 4
33 9 6
37 5 7
12 9 10
```

First integer is starting point of a building, second one is height of the building and third one is width of the building. So, how can I re-write this code? I edited my code to be more proper.

Comment: Start with proper formatting of this code.

Comment: What you mean by propoer formatting? I am not that pro in coding, so any comment will improve me.

Comment: Proper formatting means: consistent indention of either 2 or 4 spaces. Ensure that the code editor is inserting spaces and not tabs, if you indent with the tab key. Brace placement should be one of the two conventional styles, either with `{` on the same line as the statement and `}` on a line of its own (not indented), or both `{` and `}` should be placed on lines of their own (not indented). You need to pick one style and stick with it consistently, and not using different styles on row-to-row basis.

Comment: I tried to make the code more proper, I don't know if it is ok. But it still does not calculate the right coordinates.

Comment: What does it actually output?

Comment: I directly copied outline.txt: `(1,0),(1,12),(1,12),(1,7),(2,7),(2,5),(4,5),(4,9),(4,9),(4,7),(6,7),(6,9),(7,9),(7,0),(40,0),(40,1128100709),(40,1128100709),(40,0)`

Comment: I don't have much experience with scanf, but shouldn't you take some extra effort to consume the `\n` from the input stream in between `fscanf` calls? Did you even check (either with a debugger or with a few simple `printf` calls) whether the building array is actually filled with the correct numbers from the input file (prior to the bubble sort)?

Comment: [`scanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/fscanf.html) usually consumes all white space before a conversion directive. The only exceptions being `[`, `c`, `C`, or `n` conversion specifiers.

Comment: Split the program up into separate functions. Start by splitting off the input_from_file() and output_to_file() functions.Test these first (hint: output should equal input ...)

Comment: Replace every `heights[i]` by `heights[j]` in `if (ptr[i].height > heights[i]) heights[i] = ptr[i].height;`; that's what you get for _not_ using descriptive names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic example of how the frame of your program should look.
The implementation of the algorithm itself should be up to you. 
There is no need for separate line counting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct building
{
    int start, height, width;
    struct building *next;
    struct building *prev;
} BUILDING;


int main()
{
    FILE *inputFilePtr;
    inputFilePtr = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (inputFilePtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("An error occured while opening the file.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct building *build = malloc(sizeof(*build));
    struct building *reserve = build;
    reserve->prev = NULL;
    build->prev = NULL;
    char lineBuf[1024];
    while (fgets(lineBuf, 1024, inputFilePtr) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf(lineBuf, "%d %d %d", &(build->start), &(build->height), &(build->width));
        build->next = malloc(sizeof(*build));
        build->prev = build;
        build = build->next;
    }
    build->next = NULL;
    fclose(inputFilePtr);


    /////////
    // whatever logic comes here
    ////////

    FILE *out = fopen("out.txt","w");
    if (out == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // modify output function to fit your algorithm
    while(reserve->next != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(out, "Build coordinates: (%d, %d, %d)\n", reserve->start, reserve->height, reserve->width);
        reserve->prev = reserve;
        reserve = reserve->next;
    }
    fclose(out);

    // possible memory cleanup 
    /*
    while(reserve->prev != NULL)
    {
        reserve = reserve->prev;
        free(reserve->next);
    }
    */
    return 0;
}
```